# Android tablelayout width android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I'm using a TableLayout containing a row of Button and a row of TextViews,Edittexts and ImageButton.

[image]

I want the button can be wider
but if I set android:stretchColumns="*"

[image]

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/line_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:showDividers="middle|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="*">


        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/scan_delivery_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_click_anim"
                android:text="@string/scan_delivery"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_background"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_7" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_2"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_30"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delivery_type"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/delivery_id_et"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="21"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/delivery_id_del"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

and I cant control all the width in that TableLayout
why the layout changed?
how can I fix it